# How to get last word name from a string

Tags: javascript

I have a word such as

```
var text = 'http://xxx:9696/images/FSDefault.jpg';
```

How to get only the word  **FSDefault.jpg**

Comment: split the string at the last `/`

Comment: `String#lastIndexOf`

Comment: What if string was `'http://xxx:9696/images'` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to split based on delimiter `/` and get the last element of the array using [`Array#pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) method.

```js
var text = 'http://xxx:9696/images/FSDefault.jpg';

console.log(text.split('/').pop())
```

---

Or you can use [`String#lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastindexof) method along with [`String#substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) method.

```js
var text = 'http://xxx:9696/images/FSDefault.jpg';

console.log(text.substr(text.lastIndexOf('/') + 1))
```

Comment: Interestingly it seems like the String.lastIndexOf() actually performs better than the other options: https://jsperf.com/last-item-in-string

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty verbose but conveys the logic.

```
var text = 'http://xxx:9696/images/FSDefault.jpg';
var parts = text.split('/'); // Split the string into an array of strings by character /
var lastIndexOf = parts.length - 1; // Determine the last word's 0-based index in array (length -1) 
var last = parts[lastIndexOf]; // Grab the last part of the array.
alert(last); // Alerts FSDefault.jpg
```

Comment: How did you answer even after closing this post?

Comment: @Mr_Green perhaps I started answering before someone went and closed this qa?